# Grammar questions

Tags: grammar

Question 1: Can we use 'much' as a determiner for size? e.g. while talking about the size a flower vase with hand gesture, do I say "it's this much?" or do I say "it's this big".

Question 2: Is this sentence grammatically correct? "Neither she did it nor did

Answer (score 1):

It's not correct to use "much" to describe the size of an item. "It's this big" is better.

More generally, "much" is used to describe an amount of something that does not have discrete units, such as a volume of a fluid.

> "How much water will fit in this vase?"

If you were referring discrete items, rather than a fluid, you would use "many".

> "How many pebbles will fit in this vase?"

"Much" is used to describe an amount of money.

> "How much did that vase cost?"

[See link here regarding many vs much](http://grammarist.com/usage/many-much/)